# Sharepoint unit testing using fakes framework

Tags: development, client-object-model, unit-testing

I have an application which uploads a file to SharePoint via client object model. Now I need to write unit test cases for this application. The problem is, I how do I write test cases for the scenarios when

1. a folder exists
2. a folder does not exist

since this scenario can change anytime i cannot hardcore a folder name. I need to use Microsoft fakes framework. But can I use shims? If so... how to use it?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

This article has a very detailed inatruction how to use tests and fakes with SharePoint: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj822928.aspx

Comment: Hi Max! If you extend this answer with more details regarding the users specific question it do qualify as an answer. As it stands now it is more of a comment :)

Answer (score 1):

According to article [Using emulators to isolate unit tests for Sharepoint 2010 applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj822928.aspx), Microsoft SharePoint Emulators provide a set of shims including `SPFolder` object, so the following test case could be used:

```
[TestMethod]
private bool CheckFolderExists(sting url,string folderName) 
{
    using (new SharePointEmulationScope(EmulationMode.Enabled))      
    {      
        SPSite site = new SPSite(url);

        //act    
        SPFolder folder = site.RootWeb.GetFolder(folderName);
        var success = folder.Exists;

        // assert 
        Assert.IsTrue(success);

        // cleanup  
        site.Dispose(); 
}
```

Comment: This is not relevant to client side object model though.

Comment: It is a pity they do not have anything like that for CSOM.